# Make bot output embeded (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

So i am making a discord bot and i wrote a **SAY** command that outputs whatever you say,

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@client.command()
async def say(ctx, *, message):
     await ctx.message.delete() # Deletes last command
     await ctx.send(f"{message}" .format(message)) # Send text from command
```

command **.say TEXT**
This will output that text as a message from the bot, instead of doing it as a normal message i need this to be a embed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a discord.Embed instance and pass it as embed param in the send function. And f-strings already format the string. If you add an f in front of the quotes, you won't need `.format()` Like that:

```py
@client.command()
async def say(ctx, *, message):
     await ctx.message.delete() # Deletes last command
     myEmbed = discord.Embed(description=f"{message}")
     await ctx.send(embed=myEmbed)
```

Embeds are not limited to descriptions, you can also add titles, fields, footers, images, thumbnails, etc.
If you want to learn about the embeds' potentials, you can look at discord.py docs about [embeds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed).

Comment: received output

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'embed'

Comment: You wrote `embed` with small e letter. You must write with first letter with upper case like I wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly tell your bot to use an embed, per default it will always send a regular message. Something like the below will output an embed instead of a text message

```py
@client.command()
async def say(ctx, *, message):
    await ctx.message.delete() # Deletes last command
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(description=message))
```

Check the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed) for more information on styling options for the embed (e.g. color, author info etc)

Comment: `message` is a string, not a `Message` instance, so instead of `description=message.content` it should simply be `description=message`

Comment: Good catch, too used to the discord.py objects